# What if a passenger forcefully requested for a food which is not available on the flight?

Tags: airliner, airline-operations

I'd never took long flights, however curios if one day I'll fly to NewYork from India and I wish to eat my favourite dish, which may not available in kitchen of my flight, what they will do? Is there something that I've to choose from the menu only? If so, I ordered one from the menu and its not available there? However I will force air hostess to get that particular dish for me, what can be done in this situation?

Comment: I feel this should go on travel.se

Comment: Yeah this is more suitable for Travel (although I'm not totally sure it's suitable there either) - you can take food on most flights, though, within reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only so much food on the plane while it's in the air. If the dish is not available then *it is not available*.

Should you then throw a tantrum and the flight-attendant judges that you are a danger to themselves or other passengers or the continued flight; the pilot will then divert the flight and throw you off at the nearest available airport. After that you may be fined for the trouble you gave them.

Comment: You can request (i.e. pre-reserve) a 'special meal' (e.g. vegetarian) when you buy your ticket. But you have to do that (let them know) in advance: it's too late after the plane takes off, and too late even when you check-in.